# Android : library that download many sort of files

Tags: android, download, android-library

I'm trying to find a good library that download files like images, .css or even video (.avd). I found Glide for the images but if possible I would like a library that do both. Do you know a good one ? Thank in advance :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

One: https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader

Two: https://github.com/AigeStudio/MultiThreadDownloader

There are loads out there. Google is the place to be instead of SO.